# Rails/Postgres auto-increment column based on foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm, rails-postgresql, pg

In a Rails app I'm building, I need what I can best describe as a contextual auto-incrementing column. Essentially, the `Bar` model belongs to `Foo` via a `foo_id` column. I need to increment `contextual_id` on `Bar` rows in the context of its `Foo`, meaning that for `Foo` `foo_1`, its first `Bar` has a `contextual_id` of 1, the second has a `contextual_id` of 2, and for `Foo` `foo_2`, its first `Bar` also has a `contextual_id` of 1. Hope this makes sense.

Obviously, this should be handled at the database level, but I'm not sure how to do that in Postgres. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you could use a function to choose from various sequences (and a trigger to create the sequences as needed). But I'm curious why you need these values? You should generally consider `id`s to be completely opaque apart from per-table uniqueness.

Comment: @mu-is-too-short They still have normal serial primary keys, the contextual ID is to aid in implementing a specific feature.

Comment: Do you really need to store them? Could you get away with a `row_number()` window function instead? How comfortable are you with poking AR in the eye and using triggers and database-side functions?

Comment: This is related and something I've used successfully http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210898/what-is-the-proper-way-to-manually-sequence-a-column-in-postgres